# Is there a way to block navigation?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that opens Gmail for `mailto:` links. I want to make it more seamless because right now when i try to go to a mailto: link it has to go to the handler and then back to the previous page. Which causes the page to reload.

Instead, i want it to stay on the page it was on. I was thinking of using `chrome.webNavigator.BeforeNavigate` but I don't know how to stop the navigation to be committed.

Comment: That API can't handle custom protocols so you'll need to process `click` event in the page or try registering the protocol via navigator.registerProtocolHandler, look for more info yourself as I haven't tried it.

Comment: I already know how to handle the URL scheme. The problem is that its redirecting to the handler page which opens a new tab and then goes back to the previous page. But i want it to be more seamless